# ifconfig down using ifconfig output

Tags: ifconfig

On RH 6.7, using `bash`:

I need to free up some IP addresses using a script.

I am looking for a way to shutdown the bonding using the `ifconfig xxx down` command.

I search for list of candidate using this:

```
$ ifconfig |grep ^bond[0-9]:[1-9] |awk '{print $1}'
```

How may I easily use the output from this command to the `down` command?

`xargs` did not work for me:

```
$ ifconfig |grep ^bond[0-9]:[1-9] |awk '{print \$1}' | xargs -n 1 ifconfig  down
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your output of `ifconfig` in your question?

Comment: Why the backslash before `$1`?

Comment: The backslash is for executing it inside a script.

Comment: ifconfig output:
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2C:59:E5:3F:80:38
          inet addr:10.39.234.107  Bcast:10.39.234.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e59:e5ff:fe3f:8038/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32018704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29213357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2704588477 (2.5 GiB)  TX bytes:42021805800 (39.1 GiB)

Answer (score -1):

Found a nice option:

```
for i in `ifconfig |grep ^bond[0-9]:[1-9] |awk '{print $1}'` ;   do 
  ifconfig $i down;
done
```